# How to do 3d rotation in fabric.js

Tags: jquery, canvas, 3d, fabricjs, html2canvas

I am working in fabric.js, I am facing a problem of 3d rotation in fabric.js.
First of all I get an image then I convert into slices, now I want to rotate each slice in Y-axis. Actually I create DIV and style it transform rotate, when I convert this with the help of html2canvas library it disturb the image on canvas.

Here is my working link.

http://production.technology-architects.com/doulat/curtains_new/3d_view/customizer.php

If anyone have an idea please help me.

Comment: Fabric.js uses the 2D canvas API and is thus limited to 2D, so apart from writing your own scan line renderer there is no effective way to transform 2D images into 3D using fabric.js. Your best option is to create a offscreen canvas at use the webGL context to render the 3D image and then use that as an image source for fabric.js

Comment: have you any reference url that I can get the webGL

Comment: WebGL is a standard HTML5 API and supported by all the main browsers and across all the main devices, Some starting points https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL, https://webglfundamentals.org/ and you can find plenty of additional resources on those two pages.

Comment: Dear I can't get your point yet

Comment: If you want to get a 3D projection of a 2D image you need to use webGL as the 2D canvas API via `CanvasRenderingContext2D` that fabric provides an interface to can not do 3D.

Comment: Hey @DoulatKhan did you able to do this in fabric Js. I also have almost the same requirement to rotate the canvas CTX on the Y-axis.  

Can you help me out?